# I heard some local speakers say "when once"

Tags: grammar

E. G

> "when once I am there,  I'd let you know."  "When once the money is deposited,  I'd make a transfer into your account"

I think one of the word should be used instead of the two simultaneously.

Comment: **When once** is less common than the one or the other alone, but the locution has been in use for quite a long time, and it's the kind of usage that would survive in regional dialects.

Comment: Where is "local"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When once* is an older way of saying "whenever". As you can see, if we put "whenever" in your sentences, they have the same meaning:

> "whenever I am there, I'd let you know."

and

> "Whenever the money is deposited, I'd make a transfer into your account"

Also, "when once" is not necessarily "redundant." See [this excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=eZENBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&dq=%22when+once%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWrdLW8KvOAhWBbSYKHdygAZIQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22when%20once%22&f=false) from

*A Celtic Christology: The Incarnation according to John Scottus Eriugena*, by John F. Gavin:

[image]

Here, both *when* and *once* are needed to get the full meaning of the conjunction. It is not just *when he was...* or *once he was...* but *when once...*

"When once" is not used much today, but it's good to know what it means when once you run across it.

Comment: Why do you think that, when once you'd replaced "when once" in the OP's sentences with "whenever", they still had the same meaning? The OP's sentences speak of a single occasion in the future. (And I think it more likely that the speakers said "I'll", not "I'd".)
And "when once" in Gavin's phrases means something different: roughly, "when" means "whereas, though", and "once" is an adverb meaning "formerly", "in the past".